# how to solve ssl3_get_server_certificate error

Tags: php, laravel, ssl, server, certificate

I am using Laravel Framework locally and I am trying to send an email through it. However, I always end up with this security Error:

stream_socket_enable_crypto(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages:error:14090086:SSL routines:ssl3_get_server_certificate:certificate verify failed.

Can you please guide me to get rid of it. I did not find a proper solution to this problem anywhere.

Comment: Can you please guide me to the solution @Steffen Ullrich

Comment: Given the amount of information you've provided the Q+A I've linked to should provide the solution. If it does not please provide sufficient details on your configuration, what exactly you've tried and how you've failed - and also on the mail server you are trying to reach.